# Handling Busy Wait While Loop in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I've been reading about busy-waiting while loops and I believe it is an issue I am currently facing due to a spike in CPU usage.

In my service class I have the following code:

```
public void checkQuotes() {
   CompletableFuture.runAsync(this::updateExpired, taskExecutor);
}

public void updateExpired() {
   boolean moreAvailable = true;
   while (moreAvailable) {
      var expired = quoteRepository.findExpired().join();
      moreAvailable = !expired.isLast();
      // More logic...
   }
}
```

Is this truly an example of a busy-waiting while loop? If so I have read that locks and the wait and notify keywords can be used to help alleviate the situation but am not entirely sure when I should be locking or calling wait/notify. Could someone please provide an example?

Comment: What do findExpired and join do?  Without knowing their implementation, we cannot say whether they're busy-waiting or not.

Comment: We need to understand what *everything* in the `while` loop does to provide a useful answer.